# Is it possible to revert file open behavior of SSMS 16.* to the SSMS 2012 behavior?

Tags: ssms-2016

SSMS 2012 used to open a script from shell integration in a new tab, re-using the session to the currently selected DB in the explorer, or the current tab's session.

The new version opens an entire new instance where I have to make a new connection to the DB.

Is it possible, through a registry hack or other means, to revert this behavior to what SSMS 2012 used to do?

Answer (score 1):

SSMS 17.3 reverted that behavior - upgraded and it's fine now.